# Time Limit On Page

Tags: php, sql, time

I currently run a online gaming website and I am trying to stop users from being able to reload the page over and over again. I thought a good way to do this would be to add a timestamp variable into the URL and if the users presses Try Again, it will update the timestamp.

I am trying to make it to where if the timestamp is within 5 minutes then the script will allow them access, if the timestamp in the URL is outside the 5 minute limit, the script will die and produce an error. I have searched and found some ideas that I have implemented, but I am still able to use the same URL after 30 minutes. My URLs ends like this: ID is the players ID number and t is a unix timestamp

```
mug.php?ID=186&t=1368036608
```

This is what I have in the code in order to try to put this in place and I hope I was clear enough on what I am trying to do. The timestamp in the URL does not update upon refresh, it only timestamps it from the point they press the mug button, so I do believe that is right.

```
include "globals.php";
$_GET['ID'] = isset($_GET['ID']) && is_numeric($_GET['ID']) ? abs(@intval($_GET['ID'])) : false;
$_GET['t'] = isset($_GET['t']) && is_numeric($_GET['t']) ? abs(@intval($_GET['t'])) : false;

$time = time();
$time2 = $_GET['t'];
$futuretime = $time2+(60*5);

if($futuretime < $time2)
{
print "Session Expired. Please go back to the profile page and press the mug button again. ";
die();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should hold the timestamp in your session not in the url as it can be easily altered.
Maybe something like this will be better:

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

$currentTimestamp = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
$allowTimeFrame = 300;
$nextTimestamp = $currentTimestamp + $allowTimeFrame;
$timestamp = isset($_SESSION['ac_timestamp']) ? $_SESSION['ac_timestamp'] : 0;

if ($currentTimestamp < $timestamp) {
   exit('Please do not refresh the page within ' . ($allowTimeFrame/60) .' minutes');
}

$_SESSION['ac_timestamp'] = $nextTimestamp;
```

Comment: Thanks. That does appear to be working, but its giving "Please do not refresh the page within 0 minutes". Im guessing its because $allowTimeFrame is not declared. What would I set this to for 5 minutes?